# Spring Boot 2 fails starting due to Hystrix?

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I started investigating to migrate a Spring Boot application from 1.5.x to 2.
This appliication has a dependency to hystrix, which does not be compatible to Spring Boot 2 yet.
When I have the following in my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error when starting the application:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:125)
```

Anybody has experienced the same?
Is there a solution yet?

Comment: remove `<version>` tag from dependency.

Comment: This does not solve it.

Answer (score 7):

I have faced similar issue while integrating hystrix for my spring boot microservice that uses spring boot 2.0.x.
Instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-hystrix.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have moved to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-hystrix.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring boot 2.0.x application starts fine with the spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix dependency without this issue.

Answer (score 4):

For SpringBoot 2.0 version artifactID has been changed. Old dependency is

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-hystrix.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

Use this new updated dependency with latest version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

for recent release `version` you can check [MVNrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix)

Answer (score 3):

After a bit further research I found a solution by adding the following to the pom file:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
          <version>Finchley.RC1</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

all versions of `spring-cloud-dependencies`seem to be incompatible to Spring Boot 2.x.x

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem starting Spring Boot 2 as well because spring-cloud-starter-hystrix was a dependency I used in my project. However I found that spring-cloud-starter-hystrix has been deprecated. I also found the feign classes I was using in there have been moved to spring-cloud-openfeign (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign). So all I did was remove spring-cloud-starter-hystrix from my dependency and added spring-cloud-openfeign instead. This works perfectly for me.

Basically I replaced

`compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-hystrix', version: '1.4.4.RELEASE'`

with

`compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'`

and Spring Boot 2 is ready to go. Hope this helps.

NB: I use Gradle, you can easily find the maven pom dependency equivalents if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem with Spring Boot 2, concisely *2.2.0.RELEASE*. My mvn project compiled well but Spring Boot application stopped starting, without showing any real hints.

The solution that worked was using the artifact **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix** instead of **spring-cloud-starter-hystrix** from the same group. Then you can use the same same version as Spring Boot to retrieve the dependency.

From old *pom.xml* :

```
<!-- hysterix -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

New part in working *pom.xml*:

```
<!-- hysterix -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time spent on researching and testing, here is what I found and noticed

I think that in the latest Spring Boot version (2.5.x), the Hystrix looks to be deprecated or I just couldn't find out way to add it as a dependency.
[image: Spring boot 2.5.x]

So I downgraded the Spring boot version to 2.3.x where I managed to run the application
[image: Spring boot 2.3.x]

So here is how my working pom.xml looks like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>org.hldservices</groupId>
<artifactId>payment-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringCloudPaymentCircuitBreakerApplication</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR11</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Keep in mind that I had to add following configuration in my Project:

*SpringCloudPaymentCircuitBreakerApplication*(main class)

```
@EnableHystrix
@EnableHystrixDashboard
```

*application.propreties*

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
hystrix.dashboard.proxyStreamAllowList=*
```